# Macro Pivot Table Invalid Procedure

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I can’t seem to find what is causing the error “Invalid procedure call or argument”
Below is the code im using, planning to make the sheet names a variable to be passed.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
 
    sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    pivotSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name + " - piv"
   
    Debug.Print (pivotSheetName)
   
    Columns("A:M").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        sheetName + "!R1C1:R1048576C13", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=pivotSheetName + "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=6
   
    Sheets(pivotSheetName).Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("For Pivot - Month")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Debit"), "Count of Debit", xlCount
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Credit"), "Count of Credit", xlCount
End Sub
```

Comment: The pivotsheetname has spaces in it so you need to enclose it in single quotes. Also it's not a good idea to use all the rows in the worksheet for the data source.

Comment: @Rory what does it mean to enclose the pivotsheetname in single quotes? 
Oh okay

Comment: Use: `"'" & pivotSheetName & "'!R3C1"` rather than just `pivotSheetName + "!R3C1"` Note also that `&` is the concatenation operator in VBA.